# How we can pass the specific browser in Return URL while payment process

Tags: checkout, mobile-browser, returnurl

I am working with the DBS Paylah Payment process.

Where for web to paylah app checkout i have integrated Deep linking Paylah app

When user select the DBS Paylah option it will open the Payment application to pay amount before that i am generating the payment request using API call from web browser itself where i am passing the Return URL

Now if user have opened the chrome browser mobile application and using the web pos and when user try to pay amount using DBS PayLah app then it is returning url perfectly but the issue is if user have selected the Default Browser as another browser then it will not redirect the result on browser where web POS is open it will redirect on the Default browser selected by the user

So how we can pass the specific browser in the Return URL where return url i am passing as below

```
$return_Url = "www.example.com/payment_success.php";
```